# How does ReactJS efficiently know which subset of the DOM to update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How does ReactJS efficiently know which subset of the DOM to update?

Is it because it uses immutable data structures internally so that tree walking is usually not required to determine if a sub-tree has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole process of diffing and updating the DOM in React is called Reconciliation and is explained here: 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html